# Почему не происходит переопределение?

Tags: c++, ооп, полиморфизм, класс, виртуальная-функция

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Im From A class\n";
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void foo() override
    {
        std::cout << "Im From B class\n";
    }
};


int main()
{

    A* a = new A;

    ((B*)a)->foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Почему выводится именно *Im From A class*? Можно как-то кастить напрямую?

Comment: Потому что создан объект класса `A`, потому и функция от него вызывается. А вот если создадите объект класса `B` и указатель приведете к классу `A`, тогда вызовется функция от `B`  - `B* b = new B; ((A*)b)->foo();`

Comment: Указатель `a` фактически _не_ указывает на подобъект объекта типа `B`. Поэтому приведение к `B*` вызывает неопределённое поведение. [expr.static.cast/11](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#11): A prvalue of type `pointer to cv1 B`, where `B` is a class type, can be converted to a prvalue of type `pointer to cv2 D`, where `D` is a complete class derived from `B`... If the prvalue of type `pointer to cv1 B` points to a `B` that is actually a base class subobject of an object of type `D`, the resulting pointer points to the enclosing object of type `D`. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: И нет гарантий, что данное неопределённое поведение в конечном итоге выльется именно в вызов функции-члена класса `A`. Например, [может произойти ошибка сегментации](https://rextester.com/NIW25652).

Answer (score 3):

Потому что функция виртуальная, так что работает динамическая диспетчеризация, так что что именно вызывать, выясняется во время выполнения. И поскольку `a` указывает именно на тип `A`, вызывается функция для него.

Если убрать виртуальность — получится статическая диспетчеризация, и компилятор вызовет `B::foo()`, исходя из типа, указанного во время компиляции. Только вот такой кастинг — приведение предка к потомку — на грани, если не за гранью фола. Для простых функций сработает, но сами подумайте, что будет, если вы попытаетесь обратиться к чему-то, чего в `A` нет, а в `B` есть? Так что в эти игры лучше не играть...

А если вы хотите получить вызов `B::foo()` через указатель на `A`, то это делается так:

```
A* a = new B;
a->foo();
```